# How to build web-end client using Node.JS to connect to Hyperledger Gateway

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hyperledger

I am having a difficult time building a client web interface for a Hyperledger system. From what I can tell, I must do the following import on my Node script:

```
import { Gateway } from 'fabric-network';
```

The import works on Node scripts but throws and error when built alongside React. Looks like an error in regards to something called a pollyfill. I am unfamiliar with this terminology. The errors which are shown in rendering as follows:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js 24:14-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js 26:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js 26:17-34

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel-credentials.js 24:14-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channelz.js 24:14-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/compression-filter.js 24:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/http_proxy.js 30:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/http_proxy.js 32:12-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/http_proxy.js 40:14-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolver-dns.js 25:12-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolver-dns.js 27:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
    - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "util": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolver-dns.js 41:14-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolver-ip.js 23:14-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server-call.js 26:14-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server-call.js 28:17-34

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server-call.js 30:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/home/tylr/Documents/energychain-login/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Preferably I would want to be able to make a connection as a client from a web-end to the gateway. And retrieve client keys from a database and set as ENV variables, at least during this preliminary stage of development.

Is this the right approach, or should the gateway be connected to a REST API which then the web end connects to.

Hopefully there is enough information here to indicate the issues I am facing, I will try to be active on checking this thread and look forward to getting responses.

Answer (score 0):

The fabric-node-sdk isn't tested and has no designs to be used directly within a browser so I'm not surprised you are having issues trying to make it work. I think you would be better off running a rest server that performs the fabric interactions and have your web application interact through that. There is an example of a rest server in the fabric-samples repo here that may help

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/asset-transfer-basic/rest-api-typescript

Comment: What about security issues? I mean, the enroll process sends the secret to the rest server (a third party). The most secure aproach is let the user interact directly with the fabric. That seems to be impossible trough web, or i missing something?

Comment: @AndreDefremont the above question was specifically looking at whether it's possible to write a web based application that interacts with a fabric network. You seem to be referring to interacting with a fabric ca server which is an optional separate component that isn't needed to run a fabric network (peers and orderers never interact with a ca server)

Answer (score 0):

if we want a truely decentralized model where user holds custody of certificate/keys, then for now, fabric does not have sdk to connect to gateway service directly from browser/web application. Here is related jira story:
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway/issues/609